# $B$ is Hermitian ,$Q$ is positive semidefinite , $BQ^2=Q^2B$ $ \Rightarrow $ $BQ=QB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $Q,B\in M_n$.

- $B$ is Hermitian matrix.
- $Q$ is positive semidefinite matrix.
- $BQ^2=Q^2B$

Why does $BQ=QB$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the spectral theorem, we can see that there exists a polynomial $p(t)$ such that $p(Q^2) = Q$.  Think in these terms: if you had a psd matrix $Q^2$ (which you could unitarily diagonalize), how would you find its unique psd square root $Q$?

---

- For any $x_1,y_1$, the function $p(t) = y_1$ satisfies $p(x_1) = y_1$
- For any $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,$ there is a (unique) $p(t) = a_1t + a_0$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i$ for $i =1,2$.
- For any $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$, there is a unique polynomial $p(t)$ of degree $n-1$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$
- There is a polynomial $p(t)$ of degree $n-1$ such that $p(\lambda_i) = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Which is your favorite spectral theorem?

Comment: $Q=UDU^*$, so it's enough to find a $p$ for which $p(D^2)=D$.

Comment: What could it be?$(p(x)=?)$

Comment: Do you know what an "interpolating polynomial" is?

Comment: How's that?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ and $Q^2$ commute they have the same eigenvectors. But $Q$ has the same eigenvectors as $Q^2$ so $B$ and $Q$ commute as well.

Comment: Why do $B$ and $Q^2$ have the same eigenvectors ?Please more guide?

Comment: Since they commute. This is common knowledge in quantum mechanics see almost any textbook. Or see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables